# Selecting Data from .CSV format and insert into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, csv

I want to select data from a `.CSV` file and insert it into a table in SQL Server automatically using a query. Can anyone help what steps to use and what what driver is used to select for `.csv` driver like

```
 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
DefaultDir=C:\TempInterface\;',
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: dear sir,i want to take .CSV values automaticaly, and insertinto  tablre strcture can u give query and steps to follow to insert the data in to table

Comment: You could use a query for that or use the "sql server import export wizard". Google it.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link for your need.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You can run something like this:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer -d myDB -E -Q "select col1, col2, col3 from SomeTable" 
       -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```

-h-1 removes column name headers from the result

-s"," sets the column seperator to ,

-w 700 sets the row width to 700 chars (this will need to be as wide as the longest row or it will wrap to the next line)

More details about SQLCMD on :

http://sqlandme.com/2012/03/27/exporting-data-to-csv-file-using-sqlcmdbcp/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx